# I delete any file in .git/object . Now can't use git pull

Tags: git

When using `git pull`, now I get the following:

```
error: Could not read f2b6ac7a7b91d2730697c5ec4ca69896997e0d09
fatal: bad tree object f2b6ac7a7b91d2730697c5ec4ca69896997e0d09
error: failed to run repack
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+Could+not+read+fatal%3A+bad+tree+object+error%3A+failed+to+run+repack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.git` folder is the core of the local Git repository. By deleting one or more files in it, you are actively corrupting your local copy.

How to fix it:

1. recover the folder from the trash bin, if possible;
2. clone a new local copy from the remote and remove the corrupted local copy.